# Problem accessing keyboard when installing ubuntu on 2021 Macbook Pro

Tags: keyboard

I am trying to install Ubuntu on a 2021 MacBook Pro.  I have copied Ubuntu to a USB drive and the installation goes fine until I get to the point where I want to start it and I am unable to access my keyboard or mouse. I have tried installing it numerous times with the same results.  Any assistance would be appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: Is it an intel Mac? Does it have M1/M2 processor?